# Getting University from Email Address

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is trying to take one's email address say `JoeRandom@harvard.edu` and try to get what school they goto from it (In this case Harvard University would be returned).  I was wondering if there is some sort of database somewhere that could be used to check the domain.  Basically just cross checking the domain to see what school it belongs to.

Worst case scenario, I could check against other users in my database with that domain and what school they goto but that would require the first user registering with that domain to enter their University.

Comment: Hmm.. in that case.. why dont you try a table which contains all the universities corresponding to the domains. Incase, some university is missing in your table, let user add the university.. hope you get what I want to say...

Comment: Check out http://doors.stanford.edu/universities.html page....Might you get some idea from there....

Comment: @LolCoder That list is awesome, very comprehensive and specifically answers what the OP needs. Perhaps you could write it up as an answer and add some code to parse that text into a structure

Comment: @LolCoder that is exactly what I need. Now just to figure out how to parse it.  I would probably use that in combination with checking domains in my database because some schools (atleast mine) are out-dated on that list.  Thankyou very much for that link

Answer (score 0):

Hay if you wanted you could try and put the data out of a site like http://www.topuniversities.com/ . It has all the contact info for all the universities in the word.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. All working and ready to go. Validates your emails.

```
<?php

$email = 'someone@harvard.edu';
$domain = substr( $email, strpos( $email, '@' )+1, strlen( $email ) );
$school = substr ( $domain, 0, strpos( $domain, '.' ) );

echo '<p>' . $domain . ': <b>' . ucwords( $school ) . '</b></p>';

preg_match_all( '/\((.*)\)/', strip_tags( file_get_contents( 'http://doors.stanford.edu/universities.html' ) ), $unilist );
$unilist = $unilist[1];

if ( in_array( $domain, $unilist ) ) {

    echo '<p>This is a verified domain!</p>';

}

?>
```

http://jordan.rave5.com/email.php